# How to get out bytes and get number from byte array

Tags: vb.net

I read a binary file of 900 bytes with much informations inside.
Like this:

```
     Dim myFile As String = txt_mydir.Text + "\MY_FILE.BIN"
     If IO.File.Exists(myFile) Then
        Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(myFile)
        Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
        Dim fStream As New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
        Dim data As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
```

All bytes finishes in bytearray 'data'.

Now I have to read a numbers written with VB6 structs into that file. Structs are mine and I know what is what and where is what.
For example I need a VB.NET 'short' number which is at bytes 81 and 82.
Among that I have all other basic number types to get out.

How to take out desired number of bytes from 'data' from specific location, with exact length and get a proper number from it (short, int, double...)?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need?

Comment: How can I give example when I need example?

Comment: Examples of the array, what values you need from it? The inputs? Surely you can give some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the methods of the `BinaryReader` to get the fields of your original struct

```
Dim i As Integer = br.ReadInt32()
Dim d As Double = br.ReadDouble()
Dim s As String = br.ReadString()
```

And so on. You must read the fields in exactly the same order as they were written to the file.

Embed it into a loop like this

```
While br.BaseStream.Position() <> inFile.BaseStream.Length()
    ...
End While
```

Comment: Very interesting Olivier, and works. But I would have to seek somehow over half of file because I have to pass more than 200 variables which is not needed.

Comment: You can fist seek to the desired position and then use an appropriate read-method.

Comment: That can be a solution. I am new to vb.net, so can you please show how to seek to desired position?

Comment: I find ;), thank you very much "fStream.Seek(417, SeekOrigin.Begin)"